# Add the resulting array of each loop to a cell

Tags: matlab, loops, cell-array

I have some algorithm including a `while` loop:

```
 while  (condition)
    % do something and return a result array B
 end
```

Let's say:

```
 -Loop 1: B1=[1 2 3 4 5....9];
 -Loop 2: B2=[10 11 12....15]; 
 -Loop 3: B3=[16 17 18 19]   ;  
 -Loop 4: B4=[20 21 22....30];
```

How can I create a cell `A={B1,B2,B3,B4}` when the loop is finished?

For my real data, the `while` loop may be looping 100 times or more, the above is a simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `end` keyword

```
% Initialise empty cell array
A = {};
while *condition*
    % Create B using some calculation (different each loop)
    B = [1 2 3];
    % Other code ...
    % Assign to array
    A{end+1} = B;
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can join your arrays either using horzcat or []. Then initialize an cell and save them into that cell.

```
%% loop
count = 0 ;
iwant = cell([],1) ;
while .....
        count = count+1 ;
    %% let be your arrays
    B1=1:9 ;
    B2=10:15 ;
    B3=16:19 ;
    B4=20:30 ;
    %% join them into array
    B = [B1 B2 B3 B4] ;
    iwant{count} = B ;
end
```